# Safari 6 - autocomplete affecting whole form

Tags: html, safari

Using autocomplete="off" on a password input is having this effect on the whole form not just the password field.

This wasn't the case in Safari 5.

Even adding autocomplete="on" to other fields in not working.

```
<form name="login" method="post" action="login.html" >
E-mail<br/>
<input name="email" type="text" ><br/>
Password<br/>
<input name="password" type="password" autocomplete="off" >
</form>
```

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: Have you explicitly set autocomplete="on" at the form level while disabling it for the password? Also confirm that it is not a browser stored username as password that is being auto-filled? (i.e. "Do you want Safari to remember these credentials?" - Not a big Safari users so not sure how it prompts / manages the credentials store.

Answer (score 1):

Tried replicating the same on Safari 5.1.7.

I've set form's autocomplete as "on" and didn't make any addition to the password field (not explicitly setting password field's autocomplete "off"). Password field does not show an auto-completed suggestion, while the other fields work fine and shows auto-complete suggestions.

Please let me know in case you need any more explanation.

Comment: You're saying Safari is not autocompleteing the password even when the form is set to autocomplete=on, that does not happen in Safari 6

Comment: In Safari 6, browser caches the form values only when the request is made to a server. If I open my form from a local file (without using server), it wont cache the form values.
It does the caching and **autocomplete works fine** by using XAMPP or any other web server package.

Answer (score 0):

Following up on my comment:

Have you explicitly set autocomplete="on" at the form level while disabling it for the password? (from w3schools.com: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autocomplete.asp )

```
<form name="login" method="post" action="login.html" autocomplete="on">
    E-mail<br/>
    <input name="email" type="text" ><br/>
    Password<br/>
    <input name="password" type="password" autocomplete="off" >
</form>
```

Also confirm that it is not a browser stored username as password that is being auto-filled? (i.e. "Do you want Safari to remember these credentials?" - Not a big Safari users so not sure how it prompts / manages the credentials store.

Comment: Yes I've tried this and every other variation I can think of, what seems to happen is that as soon as one field has autocomplete set to off that will affect the whole form.

Comment: Strange. I have a text box somewhere here with Safari on it. If I can get a few minutes I will try and duplicate this.

Comment: Just adding that my test box is not in fact functional - but I did see a lot of people complaining about auto-complete/auto-fill issues after upgrading to Safari 6 when searching in Google. Spoon.net apparently does not have 6 available for testing yet.

Comment: Also - have you confirmed the issue on other Safari 6 installs? is it possible it is a bug you are experiencing on your testing setup only?

Comment: I haven't no but I am testing on the latest release for mountain lion

Comment: I would confirm this on another setup if you can - just given that it is kind of weird.

Answer (score 0):

try adding  a '/' at the end of the password input tags

```
 <input name="password" type="password" autocomplete="off"/>
```